# Configuring url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to change URL with htaccess. I have found similar questions here but they cannot work in my case.

My current url is:

> website.com/find-our-office-near-you/index.php?sn=visit-our-office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama

How i want it to look:

> website.com/find-our-office-near-you/Visit-our-Office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama

Comment: do you want `visit` to `Visit`?

Comment: Hi pedro, i have tried 5,6 solutions. The last one is RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^find-our-office-near-you/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php?sn=$1 [L,NC,R=302]

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. What does "what i am trying to get" actually mean? An internal redirection? An external on? Why don't you simply change the code that produces that URL in the first place?

Comment: Hi Agam, not really just the url format

Comment: What does "but they cannot work in my case." mean - Why can't they work in your case? Sounds like a default redirection.

Comment: By the way, that first URL is invalid, you cannot have commas inside a URL. It should be `https://website.com/find-our-office-near-you/index.php?sn=visit-our-office-in-Auburn%2C36801%2CAlabama`...

Comment: Hi Xatenev, it doesnt work because alot of people just asked to format 2 slashes url, and mine url contains ?sn= and commas in adress. I tried 5,6 solutions and none of them would change the url.

Comment: @JessicaHoamster check my answer please,and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Rule in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sn=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATE**
Paste the htaccess in the same folder like below

```
find-our-office-near-you
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
```

This will use the url like

`http://localhost/find-our-office-near-you/Visit-our-Office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama`

Comment: That won't convert the dashes into commas.

Comment: Doesn't work, i have changed commas to dashes in location format now. folder/index.php?sn=visit-our-office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama

Comment: Is it possible to cut ?sn= from url?

Comment: `sn` won't show in the url . You can call the url like `http://localhost/stackoverflow/find-our-office-near-you/visit-our-office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama`

Comment: Nothing happens, am i doing something wrong? I have created the .htaccess file in the /find-our-office-near-you/ folder. While the main folder is wordpress website with it's .htaccess file.

Comment: add .htaccess in outer folder of `find-our-office-near-you` not inside this folder. If you need to add htaccess in this folder, i will need to update the answer.

Comment: I am getting 500 Internal Server Error for /find-our-office-near-you/ folder. main page works

Comment: @JessicaHoamster Where is .htaccess located now?

Comment: In the main folder, i have deleted htaccess from /find-our-office-near-you/ folder

Comment: @JessicaHoamster updated the answer. can you please check now?

Comment: @JessicaHoamster updated the answer. was my mistake. fixed it

Comment: Agam, not found error is gone, but in the link there is still a ?sn=

Comment: how are you creating the urls?

Comment: Thought a href only  like <a href ="?sn=visit-our-office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama"></a>, when clicked it goes to page where i use <?=$_GET['sn']?> to populate location info.

Comment: try using this `<a href ="/visit-our-office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama"></a>`. You will get the $_GET['sn']. The url `http://localhost/stackoverflow/find-our-office-near-you/index.php?sn=visit-our-office-in-Auburn-36801-Alabama` will return the `GET`

Comment: Agam. the link WORKS NOW! but there is no images,css, on the page. Looks like this htacces is messing with source files. I will try now to enter full link. I have tried with full source link and doesnt work.

Comment: I have fixed source files with adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  before rewrite rule. Please add that as solution to question so i can accept the Answer. Thank you once again Agam!

Comment: @JessicaHoamster I have updated the answer. Great it worked . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?find-our-office-near-you/(.*?),(.*?)/?$ /find-our-office-near-you/index.php?sn=$1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: It's not working. Basically i am trying to cut index.php?sn= from URL.